# Someone is sending email from my address. How can I prevent this from happening

Tags: email, hacking

I received a bunch of `Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender` messages and found out that someone is sending this email to random addresses:

```
Today we are reaching out to people, brothers and sisters with good faith
who could help us raising 20 thousand USD to finish the building project in the next 8 months.

Would you help us further our efforts with any amout of donation? With this donation, you will help us buy desperately needed supplies.
The journey may be long and the sacrifices tough. But, God will not forget to bless YOU for a single penny you put into this blessed project.
At then end we want to thank you from the bottom of our heart.
God will bless you and your family for your prayers and donation to that project.

we are ONE BODY IN CHRIST!

Thank you!
We are also looking for volunteers to help us out in our weekly cleanup. Volunteers can assist in various ways such as:
Serving food during lunch
Cleaning up after each food service
Greeting and helping to seat those seeking assistance

Donate Now (goes to paypal donate to faith4Lord@protonmail.com)
```

Here is some message

```
Delivered-To: contact.MYDOMAIN.pr@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:ac9:5895:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id j21csp6082980oco;
        Sun, 29 Sep 2019 10:36:08 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: APXvYqwb7DDic8yrI4omnRCaKFnS68rGxyqmS2ghKYrXb7R3GNWOB6InBt02dS4UwmhYzhvGbdhn
X-Received: by 2002:a62:7a12:: with SMTP id v18mr17148713pfc.205.1569778568068;
        Sun, 29 Sep 2019 10:36:08 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1569778568; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=OqbXVSyshbH9WBJtXnl/ZEBUVPHLpQYfoM3VsvHJf/+yOrIRMKeG0nP2C8NehBZmuP
         lajwl8Mz9gGLs2Y0ZeS4dX2MsCEdsWq394Mxgqvg1ckue8jPhlSo9+qX0G0eTdfa7BMZ
         wqzatQK7rjcbj+eGT3fEUCcrX4sm7LTOneFo2gr/jShN/MSUzu0BJcELEj4PbpCzixlk
         THzuDQhnsEIa7jOd1gX0/5gfr+tFf6LlHq2VGJjwDfZH/h57SdSj0frzIHb1lFMph0sT
         mvB+Pbr9OrFwguRoSYN6yJPRohIdUyng7iXMxNxtOxzXbcTMLOltQgz3+1YgmzLUUGLi
         pR5w==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=references:mime-version:message-id:to:in-reply-to:subject:from:date
         :dkim-signature:dkim-filter;
        bh=a+zRyJwS5vnjGvzGnk9p++AVLvvCcJNTmPagml2VeVE=;
        b=OjWyu9Ps3fIM2BE9tMUaIo3NtWjsiTh3rkaYVRiLZcPAEej5+6IrsmwDVvF70N9Z2n
         wnwp5ImQMv0r518SOWyHBsDiqZ73FWkpJ/YkyXsi5RX9H9MmgAna1bhs7BexqBH9En2Z
         Fbw/PHM4taBMAbcHqjUMFXfwy7qkAbHVybFTzhpO7TbeccaLGGWBBtIW3lJPKsT4AE7M
         ZWYR3BdrFA5d6YoD65p/MhLKX6bkamMbZv6MZfTVZtyqMPLLgaQwKaKpgQpDXeorU+kl
         m7oS5VarZgjbohJb47fP0F3fAfc6WogtB6WKurU1qqSeggarBSS63BxOKvhnrxymfiJN
         R+LQ==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@registrar-servers.com header.s=default header.b=Djo6TlEG;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of postmaster@eforward1a.registrar-servers.com designates 162.255.118.243 as permitted sender) smtp.helo=eforward1a.registrar-servers.com;
       dmarc=fail (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=mac.com
Return-Path: <>
Received: from eforward1a.registrar-servers.com (eforward1a.registrar-servers.com. [162.255.118.243])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id b19si12229361pge.288.2019.09.29.10.36.07
        for <contact.MYDOMAIN.pr@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Sun, 29 Sep 2019 10:36:08 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of postmaster@eforward1a.registrar-servers.com designates 162.255.118.243 as permitted sender) client-ip=162.255.118.243;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@registrar-servers.com header.s=default header.b=Djo6TlEG;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of postmaster@eforward1a.registrar-servers.com designates 162.255.118.243 as permitted sender) smtp.helo=eforward1a.registrar-servers.com;
       dmarc=fail (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=mac.com
Received: from se18.registrar-servers.com (se18.registrar-servers.com [198.54.122.198]) by eforward1a.registrar-servers.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 4F263662A4A for <mail@MYDOMAINy.com>; Sun, 29 Sep 2019 13:36:07 -0400 (EDT)
DKIM-Filter: OpenDKIM Filter v2.11.0 eforward1a.registrar-servers.com 4F263662A4A
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=registrar-servers.com; s=default; t=1569778567; bh=a+zRyJwS5vnjGvzGnk9p++AVLvvCcJNTmPagml2VeVE=; h=Date:From:Subject:In-reply-to:To:References; b=Djo6TlEGyPuxNtbeFNnfQpLZvvL/6bJkZmW6XEDBvg+VjDrOIloB3nGdjQ1d/tEEB
     7hfl6R5OgzlFXDRkEuMGJadYxlEnRveSEpyIzeK53nbVGliC7r3xEqnpqQCTJDD2if
     jL7aNjhsZy7H/a0VxUsxNERaxUHp1TswtuGV7n6E=
Received: from pv50p00im-zteg10011401.me.com ([17.58.6.41]) by se18.registrar-servers.com with esmtps (TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256) (Exim 4.89) id 1iEd75-0005UT-Ad for mail@MYDOMAINy.com; Sun, 29 Sep 2019 10:36:07 -0700
Received: from ms67016.mac.com (pv48p67im-ms67016.me.com [10.33.35.27]) by pv50p00im-zteg10011401.me.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 6EDFD9001E1 for <mail@MYDOMAINy.com>; Sun, 29 Sep 2019 17:36:02 +0000 (UTC)
Received: from process-daemon.ms67016.mac.com by ms67016.mac.com (Oracle Communications Messaging Server 8.0.2.3.20180628 64bit (built Jun 28 2018)) id <0PYL00O00SB7P800@ms67016.mac.com> for mail@MYDOMAINy.com; Sun, 29 Sep 2019 17:36:02 +0000 (GMT)
Received: from ms67016.mac.com (Oracle Communications Messaging Server 8.0.2.3.20180628 64bit (built Jun 28 2018)) id <0PYL00809SW2TK00@ms67016.mac.com>; Sun, 29 Sep 2019 17:36:02 +0000 (GMT)
Date: Sun, 29 Sep 2019 17:36:02 +0000 (GMT)
From: Internet Mail Delivery <postmaster@ms67016.mac.com>
Subject: Delivery Notification: Delivery has failed
In-reply-to: <zR1CZk-1ibv6w2YKb-00WNac@infong1574.kundenserver.de>
To: mail@MYDOMAINy.com
Message-id: <0PYL0080BSW2TK00@ms67016.mac.com>
MIME-version: 1.0
Content-type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status; boundary="Boundary_(ID_P895vVhd0PD96r7pdj6AvA)"
References: <zR1CZk-1ibv6w2YKb-00WNac@infong1574.kundenserver.de>
X-Sender-Warning: pv50p00im-zteg10011401.me.com has no MX records
X-SpamExperts-Class: unsure
X-SpamExperts-Evidence: Combined (0.35)
X-Recommended-Action: accept
X-Filter-ID: Mvzo4OR0dZXEDF/gcnlw0dWQ8c9lblW44odAlK6ziUapSDasLI4SayDByyq9LIhVyLlira2ZKMxN sklsliJgskTNWdUk1Ol2OGx3IfrIJKywOmJyM1qr8uRnWBrbSAGDJn/eiV8ngps3HpgQfHX4epj9 EvBvwu01uVCaGVBWGqurr8tnhzcP8+kiBYbQyzvi2kDN/MHG/tk+OBQVEowst8diXwFK6bHGOGbP QfJMn6YL1eMfTtpF2Ne0CNAYQ7BTxk+YObeCHrFOq7g4KCbsxqbilSFi9Iy57rAhsKb3ET98HYiQ werCikpdDoQ79eReyIj+l51V7KOG0vlGrwU9BRR/NTbUY8nIFBUDv+N1Ac2QDSdTmwBEBCI2FjyD VZx81NYfzSiHZePL639uDyoBBM+/F64YI01J+bDECJtRVwp9jOejUEx11GDBr99qVULsgfFrL392 7nPLXidUYhzTL+cDRJjcuaPTG1Z4fuyqmWdXgU9WZf9Roe3/x2xyr8PYehIqUczFWeS6sE8e1b5/ UmXzXCq5d4y1WokT7tIr0gbcGxcnxwHiCu9ny2VznQ/9FRCRWqAFrubZmsOKYvoqjj+QhUY0Xzed jydpWs2mWGGnuvxMen7SNVRd34DwGzJ16aPTi+KGcqcrErNRBAPAnYMVQ/sEQS4vpExKuYgdapHX ROjmrvn+B7XlaePz4cFAEOvIgFeNiO5f5J0mnI43eHX+aadCSCXImm1cCw7Vzat850lX1spXJU5h BEBIE4yxU57hZeqMTQ79/D395zERYsStknsMa5xMcOok/WzPHhnWGThxvPo4BRZV4B6ksEN09R/2 gMGq0KWAzmMf+ibVDh7v0WKWBTLvzLYPCZptjo+UeVkDplwAJKmaOHmXQ3sKWHcHG2SVHESZJjYD K9pICVsgvFAJ/YpHzRuRChks7Ggatd1bXT2D6UAyQBvI2WhOnV6nT7WoFNiTLxGf9pXsDQ==
X-Report-Abuse-To: spam@se5.registrar-servers.com

--Boundary_(ID_P895vVhd0PD96r7pdj6AvA)
Content-type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-language: en-US

This report relates to a message you sent with the following header fields:

  Message-id: <zR1CZk-1ibv6w2YKb-00WNac@infong1574.kundenserver.de>
  Date: Sun, 29 Sep 2019 19:35:59 +0200
  From: "St. Paul" <mail@MYDOMAINy.com>
  To: afangman1@icloud.com
  Subject: =?utf-8?B?YWxlcnQ=?=      29/09/2019 07:31:29

Your message cannot be delivered to the following recipients:

  Recipient address: afangman1@icloud.com
  Reason: Over quota


--Boundary_(ID_P895vVhd0PD96r7pdj6AvA)
Content-type: message/delivery-status


--Boundary_(ID_P895vVhd0PD96r7pdj6AvA)
Content-type: message/rfc822

Return-path: <mail@MYDOMAINy.com>
Received: from ims-ms-daemon.ms67016.mac.com by ms67016.mac.com (Oracle Communications Messaging Server 8.0.2.3.20180628 64bit (built Jun 28 2018)) id <0PYL00809SW2TK00@ms67016.mac.com>; Sun, 29 Sep 2019 17:36:02 +0000 (GMT)
Received: from ms11p00im-qufv17091201.me.com ([17.58.36.60]) by ms67016.mac.com (Oracle Communications Messaging Server 8.0.2.3.20180628 64bit (built Jun 28 2018)) with ESMTP id <0PYL0091YSW2CSB0@ms67016.mac.com> for afangman1@icloud.com; Sun, 29 Sep 2019 17:36:02 +0000 (GMT)
Received: from mout.kundenserver.de (mout.kundenserver.de [212.227.126.131]) by ms11p00im-qufv17091201.me.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 3AC8082099F  for <afangman1@icloud.com>; Sun, 29 Sep 2019 17:36:01 +0000 (UTC)
Received: from infong1574.kundenserver.de ([82.165.85.217]) by mrelayeu.kundenserver.de (mreue011 [172.19.35.7]) with ESMTPA (Nemesis) id 1M9WiK-1iBLqt2iIO-005coD for <afangman1@icloud.com>; Sun, 29 Sep 2019 19:35:59 +0200
Received: from 41.104.178.221 (IP may be forged by CGI script) by infong1574.kundenserver.de with HTTP id zR1CZk-1ibv6w2YKb-00WNac; Sun, 29 Sep 2019 19:35:59 +0200
Received-SPF: neutral (magent0728.usmsc04.pie.apple.com: 212.227.126.131 is neither permitted nor denied by domain of mail@MYDOMAINy.com) receiver=magent0728.usmsc04.pie.apple.com; client-ip=212.227.126.131; helo=mout.kundenserver.de; envelope-from=mail@MYDOMAINy.com
Date: Sun, 29 Sep 2019 19:35:59 +0200
From: "St. Paul" <mail@MYDOMAINy.com>
Subject: alert
      29/09/2019 07:31:29
To: afangman1@icloud.com
Cc: Array@mac.com
Message-id: <zR1CZk-1ibv6w2YKb-00WNac@infong1574.kundenserver.de>
Content-type: text/html
Content-transfer-encoding: base64
Precedence: bulk
x-dmarc-info: pass=none; dmarc-policy=(nopolicy); s=u0; d=u0
x-dmarc-policy: none
X-Sender-Info: <580557583@infong1574.kundenserver.de>
X-Provags-ID: V03:K1:eKLvcgLLSrABT2fSBReezs9cYpub2hxumSfMzQmB8wZvtNjLc7s I0037xZDEVPYvUIqmrC9DAyStDRKoAzLe6SArfKP7FV3go7352BFRX2lipkip1vjk5lXvBO N9XvwpBPAUPoEK7v4tC22pSUGyjcZntRgUfsGhJYkh6BM9JJKpTrC/wdcDrhSKrciRo8NvS Oya0YJevHzrSoSwF9aixSGfHOgqiXqY0SJXD8TQHrs=
X-UI-Out-Filterresults: notjunk:1;V03:K0:CuAM3Fc3pns=:FPGv84x5VO99UnWSIEGg3e U0JKjewGANFXap145ErjKIoiVVrB56I67uBp/F7RKTjHxjHDijriltXYpnkbSXP+CJNJQGOsf xrERrOTAsXqJNZSGypx2Pk9mDrGTzMwuZxkt4SsplpKYtd7WRYkhBIjw5UbVQVoOWwa0L+a7A a70x8Or4eq1lI+JE2pDhHee/zlSalxvlgx6lQ2Y9fbP+FN9BFousKyIivQLqD962vRQdte0Ue N59LvwHaS55AqNdbg7QZurGWM4LbbzA1O83vt/p2jcrWUZMp5qH3m2ykBJlUoE5fCZl6X7sUu jMQKw0vDU2VZmfJ0ZQIOzeRHHaJ0Da/DbkhnqX6bOcN23+4ixwhs+EKtMDHiS6ElajifF4Wc0 83m+Xrw1AZLojgT0VukcLFoIrz+YfV8VPPdNvhQzI3YLQ2Y2GoNTJtSkCMRZAchjISQ2H9zzg AA9T4LkEHyQORCtTMeQIdCrZWNI1PyH9CE5F/JS3lVLuQPuCOU0tM21Gbw5hh7HVBs0+s+zk6 Jzo2PnxpLY7RNAu+ExEjFFcPR/yoM8vag+J3k002njkbGqCekk67oDrLaeyIsT5rmiItAY/KQ /NvBEG2l25Ot/mR+o9eC33dzSVvhPnkN7MTVkzjRBzHNvCmRAxbe/Qx0o3ca/fQSsOgwHzbx3 RGS/p03JA5K3TS8MJ8F2/MRzaLboHcvRxQcC1cCmuYqoKYHNlkndT3oUub28Mh34uq/F2yfH+ 7i2Y3ezHuNVYd7GCcdhSIhZa3FWm2EDONuDJzUPfTmI4PzZlseLIj4pq16x/iuWXsGnkJbphB 6L+6d8X2hhu+ApCxMvoJR7ilHgOwGAXQFXvhy+REEuD4DPv4smuF9hVCYlJQjWYap7SdSHaKC aSECP8nLYrI2E0RNyeyNEbqsnQOCVZqv8qbwWy/y2NxmX2sCLIfMFzRd6/QkY2NmmNVC4FRjJ G2givwGIsbHJVZoX4ZwQcJAg+v6c67UPQGZh8TrBhkRrbojQy5+rjrFRLg5+DPbOudjrJPk6f 9Rv7XR1aVBC7AxaZUf/+HCNOt9CiNZFA91t5SSdJFSeONDnXqcdJXBkTZUO/fFbXsA==
X-MANTSH: 1TEIXR1kbG1oaGkNHB1tfTFwbHRgZGx8aGxEKTEMXGxoEGxsYBBsbGgQeGRAbHho fGhEKTFkXBx0RCllEF2ATe0ATTEIBTUdQEQpZTRdtWE9TEQpZSRcYGhpxHBgGGxh3BhISBhoGB xsaGkIdBh8fBgcYGhpxGhAYEhx3BhoGBx8aBhoGGgYaBhpxGhAadwYaEQpZXhdoY3kRCkNOF1p 8Hn1DHHB8G1MZS0YYeAV4T3BQR1oZYn1IWR16Hlt4EQpYXBcZBBoEHhkHHRwSSx0fH0kFGxoEE wQbEgQYGhoQGx4aHxoRCl5ZF39SWmtJEQpNXBcbGxsRCkxaF2lkbllDTREKTEYXTWtrEQpDWhc YGxgEGBgdBBsYHAQbGRsRCkJeFxsRCkJFF2RbQFAfU1tgH1kdEQpCThdpa0RabxltRXxpSBEKQ kwXel5aTnBmZkVpaUERCkJsF2teHk1hbGleaUtMEQpCQBdrW3tLBWBmEgVlYxEKQlgXbG4ZUnh DYGJmUm0RCnBnF2ZfE1x7ewVhXWlfEBoRCnBoF2YFSFsBTXtrYBhoEAccGhEKcGgXbX5lWB18f HIcWlwQGhEKcGgXaU4ZRnxsQx1SRAEQBxwaEQpwaBdlYW1iax1nEmxDQBAHHBoRCnBoF2kbQVt bf2xNbUhDEAccGhEKcH0Xem54eBwbWQVdfxsQBxsdGBEKcH0XaF5HfUZrfnlQTWIQBxseHxEKc H0XbVplbEJbRl97ZH4QBx0aEQpwfxduUGZpbWxfbkVQfRAHGxgdEQpwXxdhQm5PZH0eGlJpThA HGx4fEQpwfxdkQUZkT0xNHR1gfBAHGx8dEQpwXxdlYm5MQUJsfEEZbBAHHBsRCnBsF3pTZ098A RNGQkJ+EAccGhEKcEMXZBhTS2lBX2NkTm0QBxwaEQptfhcaEQpYTRdLEQ==
X-CLX-Shades: Grey
X-CLX-UShades: None
X-CLX-Score: -7
X-CLX-UnSpecialScore: None
X-CLX-Spam: true
Authentication-results: magent0979.usmsc04.pie.apple.com; dmarc=none header.from=MYDOMAINy.com
Authentication-results: magent0716.usmsc04.pie.apple.com; dkim=none
Authentication-results: magent0728.usmsc04.pie.apple.com; spf=neutral (magent0728.usmsc04.pie.apple.com: 212.227.126.131 is neither permitted nor denied by domain of mail@MYDOMAINy.com) smtp.mailfrom=mail@MYDOMAINy.com
X-Spam-Flag: NO
X-Spam-Flag: yes
X-Proofpoint-Virus-Version: vendor=fsecure engine=2.50.10434:,, definitions=2019-09-29_10:,, signatures=0
X-Proofpoint-Spam-Details: rule=notspam policy=default score=0 suspectscore=4 malwarescore=0 phishscore=0 bulkscore=100 spamscore=0 clxscore=-7 mlxscore=0 mlxlogscore=490 adultscore=0 classifier=spam adjust=0 reason=mlx scancount=1 engine=8.0.1-1906280000 definitions=main-1909290200
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--Boundary_(ID_P895vVhd0PD96r7pdj6AvA)--
```

We are using AWS SES for sending programmatically, but I checked and the stats look normal. What else could have been hacked? I have contact@mydomain.com added to several gmail accounts as a supplementary account, but I haven't received any warning emails.

Was my registrar hacked?

Comment: https://mxtoolbox.com/Public/Tools/EmailHeaders.aspx?huid=26a69647-22cf-4b12-982e-806592b2e979 check your mail here

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Apple tried to verify the sender by checking for your SPF record, but your domain didn't have one. You should create an SPF record for your domain.